# How do I correctly set up Wine for Pivot Animator?

Tags: wine

Pivot Animator had just about no alternatives for Linux and the only advice I find is to use Wine. I have no idea how to install the thing, let alone use it. I heard it was a program that allowed people to run programs normally intended for Windows, like Pivot Animator.exe. I downloaded from the software center under the impression that it couldn't be *that* complicated to set up, I was wrong.

I quickly discovered that something was wrong when I attempted to open it with Wine and it, every single time, tried to install Tete and ***nothing else.***

I seriously have no idea what to do to set it up so that it'll run properly. Do you think you could help me out? To put into context how inexperienced I am, I have no idea how to use the terminal but understand it's a key component to the way Linux(Ubuntu?) works. I know how to follow along, but on my own I'm like a toddler learning to swim with no one to guide it...

Comment: Terminal or "command line" is a key component in all the 3 major OS families. That includes Windows. Any Windows SysAdmin use it daily. I'll investigate about Pivot Animator and may answer later.

Comment: As explained in the answer below, the latest version doesn't work (I have no idea why) but I got you one that does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pivot Stick Animator 4.1.10 installs and opens correctly. The current version downloaded from the official website does not.

1. Uninstall the version you already installed (probably optional but just in case): Open Dash and search "wine", click the icon "Uninstall..." and uninstall "Tete"
2. Download the version that works from here (link removed due to Malware). Extract and run `setup.exe` with the Wine installer.
3. Search "Pivot" in Dash, run it and enjoy!

Comment: Reviving a dead thread here but the file which you download from the link suggested by user589808 contains viruses as shown by [VirusTotal](https://www.virustotal.com/#/file/4248d6141ae8cafcfe36620a30f6a861fcce86e22600d1503564fb431eeb19ae/detection).